# Storing PHP DateTime Intervals in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, strtotime

I'm trying to schedule maintenance notifications based on the date last completed + a date time interval selected by the user.  I tried using strtotime but found it unreliable with leap years, short months, etc. The original drop down list was based on this array.

```
    $this->freq_ops = array(
        '1 weekdays' => 'Every day',
        '2 weekdays' => '2 days',
        '3 weekdays' => '3 days',
        '1 weeks' => 'Every week',
        '2 weeks' => '2 weeks',
        '3 weeks' => '3 weeks',
        '1 months' => 'Every month',
        '2 months' => '2 months',
        '3 months' => '3 months',
        '6 months' => '6 months',
        '9 months' => '9 months',
        '1 years' => 'Every year',
        '3 years' => '3 years',
        '5 years' => '5 years');
```

Now I'm trying to use DateTime objects.  What's the ideal method to store a date time interval in MySQL and still show a friendly (or somewhat friendly) text string representation in the interface?